# I cant find the right way to adjust my neural netwrok

Tags: c++, neural-network

I want to input 3 numbers which could be 1.0 or 0.0 and the neural network to predict the output based on my array. I cant find what the problem is I tried many things but nothing worked. I changed the learning rate and some functions but it made it worse. This is the code that has the least amount of mistakes. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Here are the functions.

```
double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1 / (1 + exp(x));
}
double randfrom(double min, double max)
{
     double range = (max - min);
     double div = RAND_MAX / range;
     return min + (rand() / div);
}
int randfrom(int min, int max)
{
     int range = (max - min);
     int div = RAND_MAX / range;
     return min + (rand() / div);
}

int main() {
```

Here are the variables.

```
int x=0;
double a, m, c,k;
double w1;
double w2;
double w3;
double w4;
double w5;
double w6;
double w7;
double w8;
double b1;
double b2;
double b3;
double target;
double z1;
double z2;
double ze;
double pred1;
double pred2;
double prede;
double cost1;
double cost2;
double coste;
double dcost_dpred1, dcost_dpred2, dcost_dprede;
double dpred_dz1, dpred_dz2,dpred_dze;
double dz_dw1, dz_dw2, dz_dw3, dz_dw4, dz_dw5, dz_dw6, dz_dw7, dz_dw8;
double dz_db1,dz_db2, dz_db3;
double dcost_dw1, dcost_dw2, dcost_dw3, dcost_dw4, dcost_dw5, dcost_dw6, 
dcost_dw7, dcost_dw8;
double dcost_db1, dcost_db2,dcost_db3;
double learning_rate = 0.1;
double a1[8][4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };//The first 3 numbers in each row are the inputs and the target is the fourth.
```

Weights and biases initialization.

```
srand(time(NULL));
w1= randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w2 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w3 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w4 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w5 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w6 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w7 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
w8 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
b1 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
b2 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
b3 = randfrom(0.1, 0.9);
```

Here is the training loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    target = a1[x][3];
    z1 = w1 * a1[x][0] + w3 * a1[x][1] + w5 * a1[x][2] + b1;
    z2 = w2 * a1[x][0] + w4 * a1[x][1] + w6 * a1[x][2] + b2;
    ze = w7 * z1 + w8 * z2 + b3;
    pred1 = sigmoid(z1);
    pred2 = sigmoid(z2);
    prede = sigmoid(ze);
    cost1 = (pred1 - target)*(pred1-target);
    cost2 = (pred2 - target)*(pred2 - target);
    coste = (prede - target)*(prede - target);
    dcost_dpred1 = 2.0 * (pred1 - target);
    dcost_dpred2 = 2.0 * (pred2 - target);
    dcost_dprede = 2.0 * (prede - target);
    dpred_dz1 = sigmoid(z1)*(1 - sigmoid(z1)); 
    dpred_dz2 = sigmoid(z2)*(1 - sigmoid(z2));
    dpred_dze = sigmoid(ze)*(1 - sigmoid(ze));
    dz_dw1 = a1[x][0];
    dz_dw2 = a1[x][0];
    dz_dw3 = a1[x][1];
    dz_dw4 = a1[x][1];
    dz_dw5 = a1[x][2];
    dz_dw6 = a1[x][2];
    dz_dw7 = z1;
    dz_dw8 = z2;
    dz_db1 = 1.0;
    dz_db2 = 1.0;
    dz_db3 = 1.0;
    dcost_dw1 = dcost_dpred1 * dpred_dz1 * dz_dw1;
    dcost_dw2 = dcost_dpred2 * dpred_dz2 * dz_dw2;
    dcost_dw3 = dcost_dpred1 * dpred_dz1 * dz_dw3;
    dcost_dw4 = dcost_dpred2 * dpred_dz2 * dz_dw4;
    dcost_dw5 = dcost_dpred1 * dpred_dz1 * dz_dw5;
    dcost_dw6 = dcost_dpred2 * dpred_dz2 * dz_dw6;
    dcost_dw7 = dcost_dprede * dpred_dze * dz_dw7;
    dcost_dw8 = dcost_dprede * dpred_dze * dz_dw8;
    dcost_db1 = dcost_dpred1 * dpred_dz1 * dz_db1;
    dcost_db2 = dcost_dpred2 * dpred_dz2 * dz_db2;
    dcost_db3 = dcost_dprede * dpred_dze * dz_db3;

    w1 += learning_rate * dcost_dw1;
    w2 += learning_rate * dcost_dw2;
    w3 += learning_rate * dcost_dw3;
    w4 += learning_rate * dcost_dw4;
    w5 += learning_rate * dcost_dw5;
    w6 += learning_rate * dcost_dw6;
    w7 += learning_rate * dcost_dw7;
    w8 += learning_rate * dcost_dw8;
    b1 += learning_rate * dcost_db1;
    b2 += learning_rate * dcost_db2;
    b3 += learning_rate * dcost_db3;
    if (x < 7) 
    {
        x++;
    }
    else if (x == 7)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

Here I add my inputs to see if the program works.

```
double l,j,o;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    std::cout << "Enter first number:";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter second number:";
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter third number:";
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    l = w1 * a + w3 * m + w5 * c + b1;
    j = w2 * a + w4 * m + w6 * c + b2;
    o = w7 * l + w8 * j + b3;
    std::cout << "The prediction is:" << sigmoid(o)<<std::endl;
}
std::cin >> k;
}
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Comment: Only formatting won't help here, you should consider breaking up your code in multiple functions to be more readable.

Comment: Is your target to implement a NN yourself or to solve a problem using NN? If second, I'd suggest taking a ready to use NN implementation.
For playing around with data, features and parameters, I'd suggest KNIME or similar (Weka, RapidMiner, Orange)

Comment: I think the code is more readable now.

Comment: I tried leaky relu for the hidden layers but it didnt work.

Comment: I would first simplify the training. Narrow it to a 2x2 XOR pattern, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the sigmoid is equal to 1/(1 + exp(-x)) and not 1/(1 + exp(x)).
I tried this modification in your program, while changing the sign of the update of the weights. However, I got about the same result as the initial program.

Moreover, the formula you want to model with your network is "1 xor a[0] xor a[2]". I made a fast research about neural network and xor modelisation, and I found that a hidden layer is necessary for that purpose.

Have you tried to model it with a hidden layer and the 'classical' sigmoid ?

I am sorry not to propose a real solution. It should be a comment I guess.

However, I am not allowed to provide comments. Hope it helps.

EDIT: I discovered two other issues in your code :

- In the training loop, calculation of ze should use pred1 (sigmoid(z1)) and pred2 instead of z1 and z2
- In the same way, at the end of main(), for test of the NN output,  calculation of o should use sigmoid(l) and sigmoid(j) instead of l and j

However, the programme still does not works. A hidden layer is still missing in the programme.

Comment: I made the sigmoid function wrong. Silly mistake. But as you said even if I correct it, it still doesn't fix the problem. Thanks for your answer you have helped me by pointing out my mistake with the sigmoid function.